# NTH-child not working properly

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

On some elements i can use the NTH-child selector, which is an 2nd level element (parent > child)
but in the child ive got a 3rd level element (parent > child > child) which i cant seem to trigger with selectors individually. it only triggers all of them or none.

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zvq172c/)

Comment: FYI, `id` attributes must be unique. Also you should post your code in the question, otherwise this question will be useless if JSFiddle goes down.

Comment: `section#top #block #innerblock:nth-child(2){
background: #ddd !important;
}`

Comment: @avrilalejandro only want to trigger indivually not all three

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you should use id only once in html.If you want what you have now you should use class not id.
second of all you only have one innerblock in your block div.so instead of innerblock:nth-child(1) you can use innerblock.

```
section#top .block .innerblock{
    background: #ddd !important;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zvq172c/1/)

UPDATE :
if you want to change .innerblocks seperatly for eatch block.use this css

```
  section#top .block:nth-child(1) .innerblock{
    background: #ddd !important;
  }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zvq172c/5/)

Comment: but than you will trigger all .innerblock elements. I want to trigger them indivually with the child selector, so I could give each one different background colors.

Comment: section#top .block:nth-child(1) .innerblock{ background: #ddd !important; } 

did the trick!

Comment: yes.so you found it yourself too ! ;)

Comment: I'm sry to say that. but my answer was correct and answered way before the answer you accepted(even thou the answer you accepted doesn't say any thing at all.just codes). as you see time of your comment and my edit to my answer is match.and I create a fiddle on that time too. @Junske

Comment: @ShirinAbdolahi you must read my answer, I explain things, It is not just codes, plus I fixed the OP's HTML :)

Comment: @ShirinAbdolahi thanks for explaning the situation